# Where can I find data on eating behaviors/habits?

Tags: data-request, food

I'm interested in data on people's eating habits.  Ideally this would be a "food journal" type of thing that has data from individuals showing what they ate at what times/days.  Ideally it also would include information like whether they were eating at home or at a restaurant.  As always, I'm interested in data at as fine a level of granularity as possible, so I'd prefer a dataset of individual records of individual people's individual meals/snacks rather than aggregated data showing how much people in some group ate on average.

Any ideas on where I can obtain such data?

Comment: This might not be in a format that you can readily consume, but : http://calorielab.com/news/2005/10/08/dr-nakamats-snags-ig-nobel-for-diet-research/

Answer (score 3):

The UK has done a family food survey for a number of years. It breaks down food categories and percentage of consumption. Has national, region, urban, rural, by age, by income, etc.

https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/family-food-datasets

I've not review this USDA dataset, but the description seems to be what you are looking for:

*USDA's National Household Food Acquisition and Purchase Survey (FoodAPS) is the first nationally representative survey of American households to collect unique and comprehensive data about household food purchases and acquisitions*

http://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/foodaps-national-household-food-acquisition-and-purchase-survey.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The USDA is the place to look for food journal data:
http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=13793

The NHANES has a food survey component:

http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/tutorials/dietary/SurveyOrientation/intro.htm